# jQuery tab loading design

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-tabs

This is my first ASP.NET MVC application and I am trying to select a better option for POC I am working on using ASP.NET MVC 3 and jQuery 1.9.1. Please suggest which option is better and why.Currently I have 2 implementations as below.

1) I am loading 3 partial views on demand in 3 different jQuery tabs. On demand means when user clicks on a particular tab, I call associated controller action (using GET) using Ajax and populate the model object that feeds the partial view. Whenever user clicks on other tabs and comes back to the previous one, since we are loading tab data on every request, the new request data wipes out the user entered data. To prevent this, I intend to use a Javascript object (one object per tab) that maps to model object. I will update the global javascript object whenever user changes data in the controls.This will allow me to get the current data. When user clicks on submit, (only 1 submit button, no 'Save' button for individual tabs) I post the JS object to the controller using Ajax. The controller action (using POST) will be executed and I can use the model object for further processing.

2) Another option is load all the tabs in the application at once with all dropdowns filled in. Let the user edit the data. I will capture the data in one global javascript (one object per tab) when user updates fields on the web page. When user clicks on submit, (only 1 submit button, no 'Save' button for individual tabs) I post the JS object to the controller using Ajax. The controller action (using POST) will be executed and I can use the model object for further processing returning partial view (or JSON ?) as response.

Please let me know if you have anything to improve in any of the two approaches.

In actual application there could 10-15 tabs with lots of controls so it is really important for me to get clear understanding on the approach so as not to land in trouble in future due to improper design.

Comment: jQuery 1.9.1 is pretty cool ?

Comment: Why would you have 10-15 tab of controls and one submit button?

Comment: It would be pretty annoying for the user to hit the Save button on every tab after entering data. Having Save button on each tab is not something I would go for unless there is no choice.

Comment: At least save tab state and data on tab change, from there the save option is a different issue to handle. You can save serialized in the session, partially committed to the DB in a transaction, on the server as a persistent object associated with the session, etc.